# Sharepoint error: OpenBinaryStream throws an error

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm trying to get a stream from a file in SharePoint using C#. Here's the code

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://mySharepointSite");
ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("domain\\user", "mypwd");
Folder docx = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(saveLocation);
ctx.Load(docx);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File fileConcerned=ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(docx.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" +nameFile + ".docx");

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream());
ctx.Load(fileConcerned);
ClientResult<Stream> str = fileConcerned.OpenBinaryStream();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

The program returns an error at the `ExecuteQuery()` and tells me that there is no `OpenBinaryStream()` method. I tried to swap the two lines but after my `stream` value `str` is null. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally figure it out. 
 In order to make `OpenBinaryStream()` works, I need to dispose the previous connection.

In other words, I think this code works:
   [...]

```
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream());
ctx.Load(fileConcerned);
ctx.Dispose();
ClientResult<Stream> str = fileConcerned.OpenBinaryStream();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();`
```

Comment: There is no need for ctx.Dispose(); statement. Only 'ctx.ExecuteQuery();' is required at the end of ClientResult<Stream>